# Bracket Tournament planning (optaplanner)

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner, tournament

I am trying to create a implementation to plan a tournament schedule per round. Als called bracket Tournament.

I am trying to use OptaPlanner for this, but the documentation is not that clear to me.

I have the following classes:

- Player
- Table
- Matchup (containing: 2 players and a table) This is my planningEntity
- Round (containing: a list of matches, a list of players, a list of tables, a list of previous matchups) This is my planningSolution)
- Schedule (containing: a list of rounds)

What I want out of this, is at least for 1 round a list of matchups from this info.

What I do not get is how to configure my rules in drools.

For example: how do I configure a rule that simply states: a machup contains two players that are not the same player.
Another one is: a matchup contains two players that have not played against each other
Finally: a table is available for exactly one matchup.

It feels not that complicated, but the documentation (including samples) are just not enough to get there.

Comment: Have you looked at the Tennis scheduling example (including it's video) and the Traveling Tournament Problem (TTP) example?

Comment: I will see what the video will get me :) but that I have not seen yet.

Comment: Thanx. my project is running now. Only now my rules do not give me the result I am expecting. I have posted a new question about this.